# "File or folder not found" after manually compiling and linking with make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ld, cc

We've got the exercise to create a makefile, which should "create a project *bbfoo*. *bbfoo* is linked from *barbaz* and *foo*. *barbaz* is linked from *bar* and *baz*. Use the compiler cc *(which is gcc on my system)* and the linker ld."

I created three simple c files:

bar.c:

```
int one() {
    return 1;
}
```

baz.c:

```
int two() {
    return 2;
}
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("bar: %d\n", one());
    printf("baz: %d\n", two());
    return 0;
}
```

and the following makefile:

```
bar: bar.c
    cc -c -g -o bar.o bar.c
baz: baz.c
    cc -c -g -o baz.o baz.c
barbaz: bar baz
    ld -shared -o barbaz.o bar.o baz.o
foo: foo.c
    cc -c -g -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -o foo.o foo.c
bbfoo: barbaz foo
    ld -lc --entry=main -o bbfoo.out barbaz.o foo.o
```

> $ make bbfoo

works without an error and the corresponding files are created. But when I try to run the project with

> $ ./bbfoo.out

it displays "File or folder not found".

It works flawless when I use gcc:

> $ gcc -o bbfoo.out bar.c baz.c foo.c
>
> $ ./bbfoo.out
>
> bar: 1
>
> baz: 2

What's my mistake? Is it even possible to link a project like this (in two steps)?

Comment: Generally, it's incorrect to have a makefile rule that creates a file with a different name than the target of the rule.  You have a target name `bbfoo` but your recipe actually creates the file `bbfoo.out`.  Your rule should either create `bbfoo` (change your recipe to use `-o bbfoo`) or else the target name should be `bbfoo.out` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess this is the case for the other targets as well? But this is a formality, it probably doesn't change the functionality.

Comment: the posted architecture of your project is missing a header file for each of the sub files.  Then it is missing the `#include` statements for those header files

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile uses `ld` to link, but your `gcc` example uses the compiler driver to link. You should do the same:

```
bbfoo: barbaz foo
    gcc -o bbfoo.out barbaz.o foo.o
```

The compiler driver may (and in your case clearly does) include a bunch of system-specific stuff that makes your program actually work. Trying to run the linker directly is usually not recommended.

You can use GCC's `-v` flag if you want to see what the link line it's really using is and copy the flags from that into your makefile if you want, too. But then you're at risk of not picking up important changes in the future.

Comment: Well, this is only an exercise and not a real project. But for this exercise, we should use the linker directly. I will look at the flags GCC uses, thanks for the tipp.

Comment: It's also possible that your shared library isn't getting picked up correctly. Check what the default search paths are and why that might be happening in your linker/compiler/loader documentation.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem, because when I don't use the -lc parameter for the last ld, I get an error ("Undefined reference to printf"). Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you use make you should stick with its basic principle which we can summarize as:

```
FILE-to-create: files-used-to-create-FILE
    shell-commands-that-create-FILE
```

It is extremely important because make compares last modification times of files to decide what is out of date and what is up to date. It is not a formality and it does change the functionality. So, in your case, you should have:

```
bar.o: bar.c
    cc -c -g -o bar.o bar.c

baz.o: baz.c
    cc -c -g -o baz.o baz.c

foo.o: foo.c
    cc -c -g -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -o foo.o foo.c

barbaz.so: bar.o baz.o
    ld -shared -o barbaz.so bar.o baz.o

bbfoo: barbaz.so foo.o
    ld -lc --entry=main -o bbfoo barbaz.so foo.o
```

Note that make has some nice features that can help factorizing this kind of simple set of rules. Like, for instance [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) (`$@`, `$^`...), [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules) (e.g. for building the `*.o` object files from `*.c` source files), [implicit variables used by the implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) (`CFLAGS`, `LD`...), [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) (look at the `CFLAGS` declaration for `foo.o`) and many more. Example:

```
CFLAGS := -g

foo.o: CFLAGS += -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

barbaz.so: bar.o baz.o
    $(LD) -shared -o $@ $^

bbfoo: barbaz.so foo.o
    $(LD) -lc --entry=main -o $@ $^
```

Yes, no rules at all for the object files, make knows already how to build them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By this statement I meant that this is not the reason for my error. And even though I agree that your version is shorter, more clear and easier to change, it doesn't solve my problem. I get the same error message when I try to run it as before.

Comment: What do you see if you type `file bbfoo`? Is what you see a binary for the architecture of your computer? Or is it for another architecture?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu on WSL, but with a "real" linux, the output is similar.

`bbfoo: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=a6d0029a96c8384ad525db45cac70d8df77b3052, not stripped`

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains a lot of shortcomings.

Suggest:

bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H
int one( void );
#endif
```

bar.c:

```
#include "bar.h"
int one() {
    return 1;
}
```

baz.h

```
#ifndef BAZ_H
#define BAZ_H
int one( void );
#endif
```

baz.c:

```
#include "baz.h"
int two() {
    return 2;
}
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h"
#include "baz.h"

int main( void ) {
    printf("bar: %d\n", one());
    printf("baz: %d\n", two());
    return 0;
}
```

makefile.mak

```
.PHONY all
all: bbfoo.out

bar: bar.c bar.h
    cc -c -g -o bar.o bar.c -Ibar.h

baz: baz.c baz.h
    cc -c -g -o baz.o baz.c -Ibaz.h

libbarbaz.so: baz.o bar.o
    ld -shared -o libbarbaz.so bar.o baz.o    

foo: foo.c baz.h bar.h
    cc -c -g -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -o foo.o foo.c -Ibar.h -Ibaz.h

bbfoo.out:  foo.o libbarbaz.so
    ld -lc --entry=main -o bbfoo.out foo.o -lbarbaz
```

Using the short cut variables found in `make` would greatly shorten this makefile but would make it much more cryptic